# Using ng-repeat over nested javascript objects to display select-options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, 2-way-object-databinding

How can I display two dropdown menus with the proper options using angular's ng-repeat directive?

### Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ijOqeXAQ/3/edit)

js:

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.templates = {
        pages: ['home', 'about'],
        posts: ['blog', 'lab']

      };

    });
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form action="" class="col-lg-12" >
       <select class="form-control" ng-repeat="template in templates.pages>
        <option value = "{{ template }}"> {{ template }}</option>
      </select>
      <select class="form-control" ng-repeat="template in templates.posts>
        <option value = "{{ template }}"> {{ template }}</option>
      </select> 
    </form>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-repeat should be used in option tags. Also, close double quotes in your ng-repeat expression.

Here your fixed [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ijOqeXAQ/5/edit?html,js,output)